# Get access to images with 2 different URLs

Tags: magento-1.9, image, url-rewrite, product-images

I want ANY image in any folder in my magento website could be able to get accessed both with its actual file name OR a .MAIN extension at the end of the file.

As an example, In case I have an image like:

http://www.whatever.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/218x330/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/i/p/whatever-name.jpg

I want it to get access with both follwoing URLs:

1. http://www.whatever.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/218x330/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/i/p/whatever-name.jpg
2. http://www.whatever.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/218x330/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/i/p/whatever-name.jpg.MAIN

I tried to adding some URL rewrite rules under /media/.htaccess but no luck at all:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)(\.MAIN)$ $1
```

So my .htaccess file is look like this:

```
Options All -Indexes
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_flag engine 0
</IfModule>

AddHandler cgi-script .php .pl .py .jsp .asp .htm .shtml .sh .cgi
Options -ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on


############################################
## never rewrite for existing files
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php
    RewriteRule ^(.*)(\.MAIN)$ $1
    RewriteRule .* ../get.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Actually NO rule working in this media .htaccess file. I tried many different other dummy rules for other purposes non of them even working.

How can I accomplish this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try put your `RewriteRule ^(.*)(\.MAIN)$ $1` above `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` because that rewrite condition means `if file is not exists`.